# Redirect console output to a file from crontab

Tags: node.js, linux, message, background-process

I have a nodeJs program that runs flawlessly when I run there from the console. 
But when I start it from crontab it runs about 20 min and then disconnects. (It reads sensors every 10 seconds) 
Of course I do not get any error messages on the console, as background programs have no console !!. 
I realize they need to be sent to a log file. 
But how?

Sincerely Poul Christoffersen

Comment: You can redirect output like so: `your_command >> /path/to/log/file.txt` but this method has quite a few limitations. Does your app run continuously or fires from time to time (it's not clear to me while reading your description)?

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly the solution. Now I can read the error message! 
The problem was that I used: 
var ssid =  execSync("iwconfig 2>&1 | grep ESSID").toString().split(":")[1];
 to detect if there is wifi. 
It worked fine from console, but not from crontab !! 
I have to find another solution, 
Maybe:
$ npm install internet-available

Comment: I suggest to use systemd or supervisord. Crontab is not meant to app management at all and has long list of limitations in such scenario.

Comment: Once again thank you. I will definitely take a look at it!